# CSS positioning works with chrome but not other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, position

The items on my [website](http://www.fblacazanovas.com/store.html) are positioned correctly when viewed in Google Chrome, as they should be left to the store box and stay inside the dark gray container. But in IE/Mozilla/Other browsers, it drops the items far down.

```
body {
        font-family: Arial, "Free Sans";
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #main {
        background: #0099cc;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 2px 0 4px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #main a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    #main a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #item_container {
        width: 200px;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-top: -360px;
        height:400px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .item {
        background: #fff;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: move;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    .title, .price {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: move;
    }
    .title {
        color: #333;
    }
    .price {
        color: #0099cc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
    }
    .icart, .icart label {
        cursor: e-resize;
    }
    .divrm {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .remove {
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: -7px;
    }
    .remove:hover {
        color: #999;
    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
    #cart_container {
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-left:260px;
        width: 565px;
    }
    #cart_title span {
        border: 8px solid #666;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        background: #333;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
        border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
    }
    #cart_toolbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 8px solid #666;
        height: 290px;
        z-index: -2;
        width: 565px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    #cart_items {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 0 0 2px;
        z-index: 0;
        cursor: e-resize;
        border-width: 0 2px;
    }
    .back {
        background: #e9e9e9;
    }
    #navigate {
        width: 545px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 8px solid #666;
        border-top-width: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        background: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #nav_left {
        float: left;
    }
    #nav_left a {
        padding: 4px 8px;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#0099cc;
    }
    #nav_left a:hover {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #nav_right {
        float: right;
    }
    .sptext {
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        margin-left: 8px;            
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        color: #666;
    }
    .count {
        color: #0099cc;
    }
    .drop-active {
        background: #ffff99;
    }
    .drop-hover {
        background: #ffff66;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add float:left to #item_container.

```
#item_container {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: -360px;
    height:400px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is necessary because you have cart_container first in the DOM with a margin-left. Non-webkit browsers (iirc) put a lot of emphasis on DOM order, whereas Chrome would be more biased towards the raw dimensions.